# Why am I getting a "statement with no effect" warning?

Tags: c, structure, compiler-warnings

The following is my code

```
/* Initialise default without options input. */
options -> processHiddens = false;
options -> timeResolution = DEFAULT_MOD_TIMES;
options -> performSync = true;
options -> recursive = false;
options -> print = false;
options -> updateStatus = true;
options -> verbose = false;
options -> programname = malloc(BUFSIZ);
options -> programname = argv[0];

while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, OPTLIST)) != -1)
{
    switch (opt)
    {
        case 'a':
            !(options -> processHiddens);
        case 'm':
            options -> timeResolution = atoi(optarg);
        case 'n':
            !(options -> performSync);
        case 'p':
            !(options -> print);
        case 'r':
            !(options -> recursive);
        case 'u':
            !(options -> updateStatus);
        case 'v':
            !(options -> verbose);
        default:
            argc = -1;
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to flip the boolean statement around each time an option is entered, hence doing something like

```
!(options -> processHiddens);
```

instead of just

```
options -> processHiddens = true;
```

However I'm getting the following warning when compiling:

```
mysync.c: In function ‘main’:
mysync.c:32: warning: statement with no effect
mysync.c:36: warning: statement with no effect
mysync.c:38: warning: statement with no effect
mysync.c:40: warning: statement with no effect
mysync.c:42: warning: statement with no effect
mysync.c:44: warning: statement with no effect
```

Comment: use `break;` between your cases please!

Comment: Lol good catch, totally forgot about that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `!(options -> processHiddens)` is an expression, and you're not assigning the result to anything.  You need something like:

```
options->processHiddens = !options->processHiddens;
```

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't even notice. Must be too tired. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Because `!(options -> processHiddens);` "is the same as" `40 + 2`. It really has no effect :-)

```
printf("foo");
40 + 2;
printf("bar");
```

you want

```
option -> processHiddens = !(options -> processHiddens);
break;        /* without break, all the following lines will execute */
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
!(options -> processHiddens);
```

*discards* the toggled value, hence you get the warning. You need to copy the toggled value back in the variable:

```
options -> processHiddens = ! options -> processHiddens;
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding previous answer, I don't think `options -> updateStatus`  is a function, because otherwise the compiler would complain with an error.

As for flipping the state, `!(options -> updateStatus)` is just a test (so to speak) to determine if `options -> updateStatus` is `true` or `false`.

What you need is this: `options->updateStatus = !options->updateStatus`